# GLSL Linking fails without useful information

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Similar titled question here: [GLSL:shader linking fail (but no log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555186/glsl-shader-linking-fail-but-no-log) but in my case, both vertex and fragment shaders are very simple and in/out variables match as listed below.

[EDIT] Code for loading the shaders are listed further down.
Since VS2010 does not support range-based for-loop, some part of the code are `#ifdef`'d.
But anyway...  I have tried the code with MinGW 32bit environment and it links OK.

Shader linking succeeds and runs fine when built with VS2010, but fails with NetBeans + MinGW-w64 and gives this log message:

```
Link info
---------
No shader objects attached.
```

Could it be something that's related with MinGW-w64 OpenGL librarys?

Here is my Vertex shader, and

```
#version 330

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vColor;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

here is my Fragment shader.

```
#version 330

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = color;
}
```

LoadShader.h:

```
typedef struct {
    GLenum       type;
    const char*  filename;
    GLuint       shader;
} ShaderInfo;
```

main.cpp:

```
vector<ShaderInfo> shaders;
ShaderInfo vert = {GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "SimpleVertexShader.vert"};
ShaderInfo frag = {GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "SimpleFragmentShader.frag"};
shaders.push_back(vert);
shaders.push_back(frag);

program = LoadShaders(shaders);
```

LoadShader.cpp - LoadShaders()

```
GLuint LoadShaders(vector<ShaderInfo> shaders)
{
    if (shaders.empty()) return 0;

#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || 1600 < _MSC_VER  
    for (auto entry : shaders)
        entry.shader = CreateShader(entry.type, entry.filename);
#else
    for (vector<ShaderInfo>::iterator entry = shaders.begin(); entry != shaders.end(); ++entry)
        entry->shader = CreateShader(entry->type, entry->filename);
#endif
    // Create the program
    return CreateProgram(shaders);
}
```

LoadShader.cpp - CreateShader()

```
GLuint CreateShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* shader_file_path)
{
    // Create the shader
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (!shaderID)
        return 0;

    // Read the shader code from the file
    std::string shaderCode;
    std::ifstream shaderStream(shader_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(shaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(shaderStream, Line))
            shaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        shaderStream.close();
    }

    // Compile the shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", shader_file_path);
    char const* sourcePointer = shaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, &sourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);

    // Check the shader
    GLint compiled;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
    if (!compiled) {
        GLsizei len;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

        GLchar* log = new GLchar[len+1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, len, &len, log);
        std::cerr << "Shader compilation failed: " << log << std::endl;
        delete [] log;

        return 0;
    }

    return shaderID;
}
```

LoadShader.cpp - CreateProgram()

```
GLuint CreateProgram(vector<ShaderInfo> shaders)
{
    // Create and link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    if (!programID)
        return 0;

    // attach shaders and link the program
#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || 1600 < _MSC_VER  
    for (auto iter : shaders)
        glAttachShader(programID, iter.shader);
#else
    for (vector<ShaderInfo>::iterator iter = shaders.begin(); iter != shaders.end(); ++iter)
        glAttachShader(programID, iter->shader);
#endif
    glLinkProgram(programID);

    // Check the program
    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (!linked) {
        GLsizei len;
        glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

        GLchar* log = new GLchar[len+1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, len, &len, log);
        std::cerr << "Shader linking failed: " << log << std::endl;
        delete [] log;

#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || 1600 < _MSC_VER  
        for (auto iter : shaders) {
            glDeleteShader(iter.shader);
            iter.shader = 0;
        }
#else
        for (vector<ShaderInfo>::iterator iter = shaders.begin(); iter != shaders.end(); ++iter) {
            glDeleteShader(iter->shader);
            iter->shader = 0;
        }
#endif

        return 0;
    }

    return programID;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code for compiling and linking the shaders?

Comment: I second GuyRT's request. Yet it's a guessing game. In addition, if  the shader sources are not inlined but read from external files, pls post that loading code as well.

Comment: I have added the code.  It's rather long.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem - but why all this mess with #define'es? If you *have to* support non-C++11 targets, you have to use old non-auto version, and it could compile anywhere, even on new compiler; why will you write auto version too, then? You're just increasing chance of mistake by quite significant amount.

Comment: It's not a production code and have certain reason to explicitly express both ways.  Sorry for messy code but didn't want to factor out the code for the question.

Comment: Then there could be only one answer - use KHR_debug and your favourite debugger.

Comment: Okie dokie, I will keep up with your advise. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an error in `LoadShaders`. The C++ 11 version of the loop:

```
for (auto entry : shaders)
    entry.shader = CreateShader(entry.type, entry.filename);
```

takes a copy of each entry in `shaders`, so the elements in the vector will not be updated. Try instead:

```
for (auto &entry : shaders)
    entry.shader = CreateShader(entry.type, entry.filename);
```

By the way, if you want to support older compilers, You might as well just have the old version of the loop.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to try the code until next week. But still, the same code links OK with MinGW 32bit environment.

Comment: What is the value of `_MSC_VER` in that environment?

Comment: _MSC_VER is compiler defined macro for Visual Studio only. MinGW does not have it.

Comment: OK - that's puzzling. I'd be interested to know how you get on next week.

Comment: The answer is already accurate. The code in "LoadShaders" in the #if branch assigns the shader handles to copies of the vector members, thus there's no valid shader handle in the original vector members, as opposed to that #else branch there. That explains the effect completely.

Comment: @Solkar What I don't understand is why the MinGW 32bit version works (which should use the #if branch).

Comment: @GuyRT Maybe he best sends a 4-liner through MinGW 32bit and plainly tries to dump _MSC_VER. What MinGW *should* not define and what that specific version of MinGW in that specific environment *does* not define may not be the same.

Comment: @GuyRT That seem to solve the problem. But don't know why MinGW 32bit version behaves differently.

Comment: I'd do as @Solkar suggests and log the value of `_MSC_VER` (probably best to do it the source file in question in case any naughty headers are defining it). Otherwise just run it in the debugger to see what's happening (after confirming the same behaviour with a debug build).